# UNIX message queue msgrcv failed to receive message

Tags: c, unix, message-queue, msgrcv

Dear Friends,
Any idea why the msgrcv is receiving a blank buffer?

Here is the code:

```
enter code here
 #include <sys/msg.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 typedef struct mymsg {
  long mtype;
  char mtext[24];
 }mymsg;

 int main()
 {
  int msqid;
  mymsg msg,buff;
  msqid=msgget(IPC_PRIVATE,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);

  if(msqid==-1){
  perror("FAiled to create message queue\n");
  }
  else{
  printf("Message queue id:%u\n",msqid);
  }
  msg.mtype=1;
  strcpy(msg.mtext,"This is a message");
  if(msgsnd(msqid,&msg,sizeof(msg.mtext),0)==-1){
   perror("msgsnd failed:");
  }
  else{
   printf("Message sent successfully\n");
  }
 //ssize_t msgrcv(int msqid, void *msgp, size_t msgsz, long msgtyp,int msgflg);

  // msgrcv(msqid,buff.mtext,sizeof(msg.mtext),1,0); This was error
  msgrcv(msqid,&buff,sizeof(msg.mtext),1,0);  // This is correct (Thanks to Erik)
  printf("The message received is: %s\n",buff.mtext);
 }

   Output:
   [root@dhcppc0 message_queue]# ./a.out
   Message queue id:294919
   Message sent successfully
   The message received is: 
                                                    1,1           Top
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`msgbuf.mtype` must be set to 1 - since you're telling `msgrcv` that you want messages of type 1.

Alternatively, you could set `msgbuf.mtype` to any positive value, and then tell `msgrcv` that you want any message type by passing 0 as the `msgtyp` argument.

Also, `msgrcv` expects a pointer to a `msgbuf`:

```
msgrcv(msqid,&buff,sizeof(msg.mtext),1,0);
```

EDIT: Tested working source:

```
 #include <sys/msg.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 typedef struct mymsg {
  long mtype;
  char mtext[24];
 }mymsg;

 int main()
 {
  int msqid;
  mymsg msg,buff;
  msqid=msgget(IPC_PRIVATE,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL);

  if(msqid==-1){
  perror("FAiled to create message queue\n");
  }
  else{
  printf("Message queue id:%u\n",msqid);
  }
  msg.mtype=1; // was there failed to copy
  strcpy(msg.mtext,"This is a message");
  if(msgsnd(msqid,&msg,sizeof(msg.mtext),0)==-1){
   perror("msgsnd failed:");
  }
  else{
   printf("Message sent successfully\n");
  }
 //ssize_t msgrcv(int msqid, void *msgp, size_t msgsz, long msgtyp,int msgflg);

  msgrcv(msqid,&buff,sizeof(msg.mtext),1,0);
  printf("The message received is: %s\n",buff.mtext);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, that line : msg.mtype=1; was already there, i missed to copy it. But still does not work.

Comment: Sorry, just a sec.let me compile again.